# How do all points $(x; \sin x)$ look in polar coordinate system

Tags: polar-coordinates

Recently, I wondered how $(x; \sin x)$ would look in polar coordinate system (where the first coordinate is the distance from the origin, and the second one is the angle from the horizontal axis). My imagination tells me, that it should still look, like some kind of a wave, but I'm not sure. So how does it look? And, btw, is there some kind of an app to build graphs in polar? I tried in GeoGebra, but it didn't work.

Comment: You could learn a lot by plotting the graph by hand. Start with the points where $\sin(x)$ is $0$ and where it's $\pm 1$. Then sketch how it might connect those points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GeoGebra works, but you have to actually use the Greek letter $\theta$ as your free variable. That's the easiest way to make GeoGebra understand that you want it to think polar.

*Usually*, you would let the angle be the free variable, take the sine of the angle, and let that be the distance from the origin. It turns out that the resulting graph of the sine function, in polar coordinates, is a circle with radius $\frac 12$ centered at $(0, \frac12)$. This is what appeared when I entered `sin(θ)`:

[image]

You seem to want the opposite, though. To do that, I looked at the definition of the `a` object, and saw that it was defined as `Curve((sin(θ);θ), θ, 0, 2π)` We want to flip the two coordinates, so that's what we do: `Curve((θ;sin(θ)), θ, 0, 2π)` gives the curve

[image]

Of course, at this point, $\theta$ is not the correct variable name any more. It would be more correct to use `Curve((r;sin(r)), r, 0, 2π)`. Now that we have figured out the actual syntax for making GeoGebra plot in polar coordinates, we don't need to use $\theta$ any more to force it.

Comment: I'm a little puzzled. Qualitatively this looks right, but the tangent vector is $(1, \cos t)$ (in rectangular coordinates with parameter $t$). That suggests that the curve should have vertical tangents where it crosses the $x$-axis at  $t = 0, \pi,   2\pi, \ldots$.

Comment: @EthanBolker Since the second graph has $\theta$ as a function of $r$, the graph being orthogonal to the lines though the origin at any point would mean an infinite derivative. And the derivative of the function $\theta(r) = \sin(r)$ is certainly not infinite at any point. More hand-wavey, if we parametrize this curve in polar space the simplest way I know how, the graph is _always_ moving outward at a constant speed, and it is never moving around-ward at an infinite speed. In particular not when it crosses the $x$-axis.

Comment: OK I see this a little more clearly. The radius is increasing at a constant rate, so the tangent vector can never be perpendicular to the radius. I'm still puzzled, but will think more later.

Comment: @EthanBolker The derivative of $f(r)=re^{i\sin r}$ is $f'(r)=e^{i\sin r}+re^{i\sin r}i\cos r$. At the points where $\sin r=0$ we get $f'(\pi k)=1\pm i\pi k$. For $k=0$ the vector $1+i0$ is horizontal, then for larger $k$ becomes more and more vertical (however, never exactly vertical).

Comment: @EthanBolker a function $\theta(r)$ plotted polar-ly will be perpendicular to the radius precisely when the same function plotted rectangularily is vertical: when the derivative is infinite. $\theta(r)=\sqrt[3]{r-1}$ at $r=1$ is one example.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the plotting in MATLAB
[image]